# Can we modify or replace kernel and shell of an Android Device?

Tags: kernel

Is it possible to modify the kernel and shell of an android device? Devices like Samsung Galaxy S6 or Xiaomi Mi4i?
If yes, how is it possible?
Does the Manufacturer need to provide the Kernel before development? 
Can we use any kernel in any Android device

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel yes, shell don't know of there is any way. By the way shell is the command line interface of android that you can access by rooting, and using busy box or adb. You can't change that as it is architecture based. Just like you can't change cmd on windows to use Mac commands. But if you are taking about firmware, then yes, ROM yes, recovery yes, boot loader no. If it answers your question.